# ios - Back ground color of status bar turns white while using scroll view

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, background-color, statusbar

I'm a newbie, trying to implement scroll view. When I use the scroll view without embedding in a navigation controller, the status bar background color doesn't change, as I wanted.

[image: Good]

But when I embed in a navigation controller, the background color of status bar changes to white.

[image: Bad]

How can I prevent status from changing its color to white when I embed in a navigation controller. Thanks.

Here is the constraints.
[Constraints](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c49MH.png)

Comment: pls add screen shot of that

Comment: Yes, I have added. Click that good and bad text.

Comment: try this answer may be it helpful

Comment: @Krunal Yes, shared it. check this link for additional reference. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LhhW3xqhCzg&t=182s

Answer (score 0):

Try this after navigation controller :

```
let statusBar: UIView = UIApplication.shared.value(forKey: "statusBar") as! UIView
        if statusBar.responds(to: Selector(("setBackgroundColor"))) {
            statusBar.backgroundColor = UIColor.magento
        }

func setStatusBarBackgroundColor(color: UIColor) {

        guard let statusBar = UIApplication.shared.value(forKeyPath: "statusBarWindow.statusBar") as? UIView else { return }
        statusBar.backgroundColor = color
    }
```

Comment: I added this code in viewdidload method, it shows this error "Incorrect argument label in call (have 'hex:', expected 'coder:')"

Comment: U have to use simple UIColor.magenta

Comment: Or use this  UIColor.init(red: <#T##CGFloat#>, green: <#T##CGFloat#>, blue: <#T##CGFloat#>, alpha: <#T##CGFloat#>) and fill the color code in feild that you use earlier

Comment: pls UpVote if helpful

Comment: yes sure. But I'm not clear with this solution. If you check this  5 mins tutorial link which I used, then you can help me easily. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LhhW3xqhCzg&t=180s

Comment: what problem u have face in this answer

Comment: The problem is. I don't want to give specific color to the status bar when it changes to white. As in that tutorial, I will be placing a UIView on a scroll view. And I want to prevent the status bar from changing its background color to white, and adopt to the color which I give for the UIView in the storyboard. This works fine without using navigation controller.

Answer (score 0):

View controller-based status bar appearance = False/True

Further there is programmable way of doing it. Please do tell me if you want that

Comment: I tried using in info.plist. It results the same. You can tell me the programmable way too.

Comment: Yeah sure, I will have to dig a little deeper in my code

Comment: override public var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle {
        if DefinedConstants.isiPad() {
            return .default
        }
        return .lightContent
    }

Answer (score 0):

That's happening because the Status Bar is sharing the same background as the Navigation Bar you embedded in. On your main view, under `viewDidLoad()` add the following code and set the background colour as you wish:

```
    self.navigationController?.hidesBarsOnSwipe = true

    /* creates a View using the navigation bar frame to place under the status bar but above the navigation bar */

    let statusBarView = UIView()
    statusBarView.backgroundColor = .blue
    statusBarView.frame = UIApplication.shared.statusBarFrame
    UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.addSubview(statusBarView)
```